# What is the best way to implement scale bars for OpenCV or similar?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I would like to implement the size-measuring app:

User has a rectangular scale bar of a known length which he places near the object. The size of the bar is already stored inside the app, so, I know the real size of the bar and I can use OpenCV to detect where the scale bar is situated so I can know the ratio of these two measurements and I can use it in proportion to calculate the other objects size.

The question is - what is the best practice for creating such scale bars? When I am detecting just a simple shape (a rectangle), it finds a lot of rects on an image. Probably it should be of green/red/yellow/any other color which can be rarely found (especially, in nature). Probably, there should be a rect inside another rect to help the computer vision library to detect it easier. Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for "trackbars" http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2011/11/track-bars.html